# Hopefully one last one about php cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I have posted a couple of questions about cookies in the last two days. I am almost finished my homework assignment, but am having an issue.

I need to allow my users as many chances to login to the comments section of my site, however, if they fail 5 attempts within 30 seconds, they are locked out for 3 minutes. To count out the 5 attempts, I did this:

```
   if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie1'])){
      if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie2'])){
         if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie3'])){
            if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie4'])){
               header('Location: reading_cat.php');
               setcookie("locked_out", "cookie", time()+180);
            }setcookie("cookie4", "cookie4", time()+30);
         }setcookie("cookie3", "cookie3", time()+30);
      }setcookie("cookie2", "cookie2", time()+30);
   }setcookie("cookie1", "cookie1", time()+30);
```

This works well, save for one problem. When the user fails an attempt, a cookie is set. If he fails attempt 2, cookie one is checked, if present cookie 2 is set, and on. In this instance, each time a successive cookie is added, for some reason all cookies have their expiry date written to the time of the last cookie added.

To rephrase: cookie 1 is added at 6:00 and no seconds, and it's expiry is then 6:00 and 30 seconds. Cookie 2 is added at 6:00 and 15 seconds, it's expiry is 6:00 and 45 seconds. I thought cookie one should remain the same, but when I check, now cookie one has the same expiry as cookie two. Therefor, all cookies in this scenario expire at the same time (and this is no good).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What a mess! Dude you should really consider to change the whole code you are using.

Comment: There's also no point in setting a thousand different cookies. Write the **number of attempts** to *one* cookie and simply check that value. That won't actually be tamper proof, but makes more sense.

Comment: Fair enough, this is the first time I have done any of this stuff. I understand making a cookie named count, and checking how many times it has been incremented, but how would I check that the user has tried 5 times in 30 seconds? A user could try 4 times in 15 seconds, then wait 30 seconds, then they should get five tries again. If I go solely of a count, there is no way to tell.

Comment: It's like a stair-master for my eyes! Thanks for the workout! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$attempts   = !empty($_COOKIE['attempts']) ? unserialize($_COOKIE['attempts']) : array();
$attempts[] = time();
$attempts   = array_slice($attempts, -5);

setcookie('attempts', serialize($attempts));
```

This provides you with a FIFO queue of the last 5 attempts and their timestamps. `$attempts[0]` contains the timestamp of the oldest attempt. This should give you the information you need.

Comment: Thanks, that is great! That's sweet. I appreciate you taking the time. Although I understand from other comments that the original is shitty code, could you possibly explain to me why the cookies re-write their expiry time? I am just curious as to why this is?

Comment: @Phill Because you're *always* rewriting the cookies. There's no `else`.

Comment: Oh shit, of course. Thank you. I appreciate it. Very obvious. Love the answer above, but if I used that, my instructor would wonder how I had learned the methods mentioned. Pretty sure he would figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not a very good way of doing it. You Should have either a session counter or a cookie counter.

Also, anyone who knows what they are doing can bypass cookies and sessions, so you'd want to block that persons IP address instead of just a cookie blocker.

Comment: This is a homework assignment, its sole purpose is in making sure we can use cookies. It has nothing to do with best practice, security, etc. Simply an exercise. I am not allowed to use session, I must use cookies. It is a clear stipulation of my rubric. As I said earlier, I could use a counter, but how would I check the user has tried 5 times in 30 seconds? The user could try every ten seconds, and should be allowed to do that as long as they wish. A counter will not tell us this.

Comment: In that case use one cookie containing the number of failed attempts.

Comment: A counter containing the number of failed attempts is just a counter, and it can't tell how many have happened in 30 seconds. That is why I did it in the way I did originally, it checks to make sure that there are failed attempts, and if there aren't 4, it won't lock out.

Comment: You can tell your teacher that using sessions is the same thing as using cookies, because sessions are tracked using cookies.. sessions are only a way to group server data with a small cookie (client data)